# How do I remove a line from a CSV file using Super CSV?

Tags: java, supercsv

I am little new to Super CSV. Just wanted to check if there is provision to delete or modify a line in a CSV file?

Looking at the source, I do not see use of RandomAccessFile in rw mode. Any way to customize this?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/11035602/1068649

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super CSV doesn't support editing CSV files.

The quick and dirty solution would be to create a copy of the CSV file (i.e. read in each line with Super CSV, then write it out to a different file). You can choose whether to modify the data or to omit a line very easily.

As you've probably seen, Super CSV works with Readers/Writers. It might be possible to write your own Reader/Writer that wraps RandomAccessFile which could then be used by Super CSV, but it might just be simpler to make a copy.